# Date of Birth Validation: Minimum & Maximum Year of Birth

Tags: input-fields, validation, legal

I am working on an app which asks for date of birth of users during signup process. The app can be used by users of all ages. Having said that, I think there must be some validation in place. In my opinion kids should be at least 13+ (which also clears [FTC guidelines](https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/privacy-and-security/children%27s-privacy)) to understand and use the app. But what should be the max age limit?

Here are some findings from the web (Format = Brand name | Min year | Max year):

1. **Google** | 2015 | 1866
2. **Yahoo** | 2015 | 1885
3. **Facebook** | 2015 | 1905
4. **Apple** | 2015 | 1865

(*All provided a dropdown menu and in all above cases, I couldn't create an account with year of birth as 2015 due to validations/legal constraints. Wondering why provide 2015 as a menu item in the first place?*)

Comment: If [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_verified_oldest_people) is correct, there are two people left who are known to have been born in the 19th century.

Answer (score 2):

While I don't think there a definitive correct answer, I'd think you're pretty safe by allowing a 100 year differential. The time you've spent posing this question will probably have cost more than any lack of revenu by a disgruntled 110y old user that feels he/she can't properly register in your app.

Comment: I was also referring to confusing validation rules of some of the most widely used brands. I hope you must have noticed that as well. It's more of an observation rather than an hypothesis. Ty.

Answer (score 0):

Giving a 100 year (since most people wont live above a 100) till the dob of your 13 year olds would make sense. then would be 1902-2002

Answer (score 0):

If you're putting an upper age limit on the sign up process, why not use the world's oldest person as a reference?

According to [Wikipedia's list of oldest people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oldest_people) - which we all know the one and only version of the truth - the longest living person alive is 116 years old.

If you use the their year of birth then you're catered for all eventualities in the future (unless a 170 year old is suddenly discovered!).